# Not getting the particular date in return

Tags: android, string, performance, android-layout

I am trying to fit this code in my application.

```
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.set(2012,12,23,10,45, 0);
            System.out.println("TimeInMillis:" + c.getTimeInMillis());
            long oldMillis = c.getTimeInMillis();
            Date e = new Date(c.getTimeInMillis());
            System.out.println("Date:" + e);
```

But the console is printing-

```
Date:2013-01-23
TimeInMillis:1358918100839
```

I don't know what is wrong with this code. Instead of printing  "Date:2012-12-23" it is printing "Date:2013-01-23". Can any one guide me regarding this?

Comment: Month value is 0-based. e.g., 0 for January (javadoc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing 12 try to pass 11 for `month`. Bcs, month will **start from 0 and not with 1**(ie.0 for January, 1 for February and so on). So, if you pass 11 then only you will get the `date` for `december` as **2013-12-23**.

Try this:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(2012,11,23,10,45, 0);          // Correction here
System.out.println("TimeInMillis:" + c.getTimeInMillis());
long oldMillis = c.getTimeInMillis();
Date e = new Date(c.getTimeInMillis());
System.out.println("Date:" + e);
```

Comment: @Andru Hope you went through the small passage of three lines above the code which consists of enough explanation about the correction before posting a comment like this!!

Comment: You know better than me when you add these lines. This site is not all about reputation. I think you should explain why you made the correction. It will be difficult for new comer why he should do the such change(for month 12 to 11).

Comment: @Andru Even a new comer will get a fair better idea with those three lines of explanation that why it should be changed from 12 to 11. If some one starts coding even if we give a brief idea of why and what for is that change he would be able to go on with that:(

Comment: @Andru Not sure why you are so picky about this. But the revision history of this answer seems to have the proper answer from initial post itself. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20737694/revisions

Answer (score 1):

The Months starts from 0 for January  to 11 for December, if you specified 12, 13, 14... it will calculate the next month of the next year,

**For Instance : If you specified the month as 14 and year as 2012, it won't throw any error  "Saying that, this is not a Valid month", it simply returns the February of next year, in our example it will return February 2013".**

so you should write the code as

```
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                c.set(2012,11,23,10,45, 0);
                System.out.println("TimeInMillis:" + c.getTimeInMillis());
                long oldMillis = c.getTimeInMillis();
                Date e = new Date(c.getTimeInMillis());
                System.out.println("Date:" + e);
```

Output

> : Date:Sun Dec 23 10:45:00 IST 2012

If you give value for month as 12 , it will take Next January 2013 , similary for 14 it will take next year Feburary

```
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.set(2012,12,23,10,45, 0);
            System.out.println("TimeInMillis:" + c.getTimeInMillis());
            long oldMillis = c.getTimeInMillis();
            Date e = new Date(c.getTimeInMillis());
            System.out.println("Date:" + e);
```

Output:

> Date:Wed Jan 23 10:45:00 IST 2013

Output if you specified the value for month as 13

> Date:Sat Feb 23 10:45:00 IST 2013

Comment: Thank you every one for posting their valuable help.

Comment: @user3106046: Please accept this answer, if it helps to you, so that the other guys when they search for this Question , they will able to know this is the right answer and that makes them to try this, Thanks

Comment: Yes this helps me well. The ans from Sankar is well. Thanks.